# Dimiss UIPopOverController within NavigationController

Tags: xcode, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am using a PopOverController and inside it there are 2 tableviews.
The first TableView is to select an account and the second to select an item, on didSelectRowAtIndexPath: I want to dismiss the PopOver, so dismissPopOver:animated won't work, any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table view should inform the view controller from which the pop over appeared for dismissing it. It can be done using a notification.